# SelectList not working (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have controller method to render PartialView and show SelectList there

Here is method code

```
public ActionResult AddProject()
    {
        ViewBag.Region = new SelectList(db.Regions, "Id", "Name").ToList();
        return PartialView("/Partials/ProjectModalPartial");
    }
```

Here is code in PartialView

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Выберите Город</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Region", null, "XXXX", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "cityId"})
</div>
```

And here is how I call it in View

```
<div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Manage/Partials/ProjectModalPartial.cshtml")
        </div>
```

Here is regions model

```
public partial class Region
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Region()
    {
        this.Cities = new HashSet<City>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

But I have this error

> > There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Region'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
> >     during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
> >     stack trace for more information about the error and where it
> >     originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is no
>   ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key
>   'Region'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 6:       Line 7:          Выберите Город
>   Line 8:          @Html.DropDownList("Region", null, "XXXX",
>   htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "cityId"}) Line
>   9:       Line 10:

How can I solve it. And why it appears if I have this SelectList in code?

Comment: Why not go for something like this? @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Id, Model.Cities, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})  you might need to fiddle around with the Model.Cities bit, but somethink like this should work.

Comment: I not using Models in Views@Lidaranis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [this `Html.Action` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29) which will call the action method and the action will return the partial view back. `Html.Partial` is just rendering the view as html without calling the action so `ViewBag.Region` is not having the value which is expected :

```
@Html.Action("AddProject","Project")
```

assuming the controller class name is `ProjectController`.

So what will happen now is that `Html.Action` will call the `AddProject` action and will return the `ActionResult` back to your view from which we have called and will render html of partial view `ProjectModalPartial.cshtml`

Comment: but in Controlller I has ActionResult. Why I need tu use `Html.Action`

Comment: @eugene `Html.Action` will call the `AddProject` action and will return the `ActionResult` back to your view from which we have called and will render html of partial view `ProjectModalPartial.cshtml`

Comment: It helps. Thank's